# Which actions for each class generate Action Points in Neverwinter the fastest?

Tags: neverwinter

Neverwinter just went open beta and I'm trying to figure out what specific actions I should do with my Guardian Fighter to refill my action point bar the quickest.

I remember from the closed beta weekend I played a cleric with a healing skill that refilled the cleric's action points, but they've changed a bit of the class designs since then and I am trying to track down an official or at least psuedo-offical answer.

Comment: If you mouse over your AP meter while it's not full, it will tell you what fills it. Another cool thing to note, is that the Recovery mod raises AP gain by a percentage. For example, 2,982 Recovery is +49.3% AP gain.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc your comment is basically the answer I was looking for more, I just couldn't find where to find that out.

Comment: I should've just said so sooner :P  But I like the list compiled in the answer anyways, because me and anyone else will be able to refer to it instead of skimming through the wiki and reading through 30+ skills for each class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may end up somewhat long, but here goes!

First of all, what exactly are Action Points?

(I just took the time to add this to the official wiki :D @ [wiki](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Neverwinter_Wiki) )

> Action Points are the method by which a character's Daily Powers are recharged. Each character has a gauge represented by a D20 in the middle of their Combat Action Bar. This gauge refills as the character gains more Action Points. When this bar is filled by the attainment of Action Points, a character's Daily Power is available for use. The use of a character's daily power depletes this gauge and a character must once again perform actions which grant Action Points to refill it. Each Class has a different set of things that cause the character to gain Action Points.

What abilities gain Action Points?

### ***Great Weapons Fighter :***

**Encounters:**

> Battle Fury   -  Increases your Atwill and Encounter damage as well as
>   Action Point gain for brief period. In addition, when first activated
>   your Stamina is refilled. This power may be activated while moving.
>
> Indomitable Battle Strike   -   Savagely strike your
>   target to shows your other foes the fate that awaits them. After
>   killing a target with this strike, you gain bonus Action Point, and
>   nearby enemies are briefly Marked. Marked targets take additonal
>   physical damage until they attack you.

**Feats:**

> Unstoppable Action     -     You gain 5/10/15/20/25% bonus Action
>   Points for dealing damage while you are Unstoppable.

### ***Guardian Fighter :***

**Encounters:**

> Into The Fray  - A fierce battle cry that temporarily increases your
>   adventuring party;s deflect chance, Run Speed, and Action Point
>   generation.

**Ability Score Bonus:**

> Constitution - +1% Action Point Gain

**Feats:**

> Action Surge - Gain 2/4/6/8/10% more Action Point for damage reduced
>   by your damage reduction.
>
> Improved Vigor - When less than 50% health, gain 2/4/6/8/10% more
>   Action Points.
>
> Martial Mastery  -  Taking damage while not using Guard now builds
>   Action Points. You gain a bonus to this value based on your Damage
>   Resistance.

### ***Trickster Rogue***

**Encounters:**

> Bait and Switch - Jump backwards, dropping a decoy in your place. Any
>   enemies that are near the decoy will attack it instead of you.  Gain
>   Action Points when the decoy is hit by an enemy.

***Feats:***

> Action Advantage - 2/4/6/8/10% bonus Action Points for dealing Combat
>   Advantage Damage.
>
> Cunning Stalker - While Stealthed, you build 4/8/12/1/20% more Action
>   Point.
>
> Action Rush - Your encounter Powers have a 15% chance to grant
>   3/6/9/12/15% of your Action Point.
>
> Thrill of the Kill - When you land a killing blow, gain .2/.4/./.8/1%
>   of your Action Point.

### ***Control Wizard***

**Ability Score Bonus**

> Wisdom - +1% Action Point Gain

**Feats:**

> Controlling Action  -  Gain an additional .2/.4/.6/.8/1% of your max
>   Action Point when you cast a control power.
>
> Critical Power - When you land a critical hit you gain 1/2/3/4/5% of
>   your total Action Point. (10 second cooldown)

### ***Devoted Cleric***

**Encounters:**

> Prophecy of Doom - Target has lowered Defense for a medium duration,
>   and if target is still alive after this time, They take a large amount
>   of damage. If target is killed during this time, you gain a large
>   amount of Action Points, and this power instantly recharges.

**Feats:**

> Healing Action - Gain 1/2/3% more Action Point whenever you use a
>   Healing ability.

**Ability Score Bonus:**

> Charisma - +1% Action Points Gain

**Class Feature:**

> Holy Fervor - Your attacks generate 5% more Action Points. Rank 2:
>   +5%. Rank 3: +5%

Also, if you mouse over your AP meter while it's not full, it will tell you what fills it.   Another cool thing to note, is that the ***Recovery*** mod raises AP gain by a percentage. 
For example, 2,982 Recovery is +49.3% AP gain.

Comment: Yes I too found this, but these power boost action points (APs). You can generate APs normally through your class features. I believe that blocking as a guardian fighter actually generates APs and other class specific actions do the same, but I want official confirmation.

Comment: nobody makes you do work on SE....

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc [That's no excuse to be rude.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette)

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc There's no need to quote everything, because the user asked only about what replenishes AP the fastest. :)

Comment: @badp that depends on tremendous amounts of math, and is extremely situational.  I think a compiled list of all of the skills that have an effect on AP gain would be a better way to answer this question. For example, the class he plays, Guardian Fighter, gains more AP at <50% health.  I can't answer : "get yourself to under 50% health, thats how you gain AP the fastest."

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc was not baiting you, I just thought it was a bit much to down vote over what amounted to my question needed editing due to miscommunication on my part.